# Is it possible to induce recvmsg to return an error?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, recvmsg

I'm writing a library that calls `recvmsg`, and now I'm writing tests for that library. I want to test the error paths: the code that runs when `recvmsg` returns an error. I could mock out `recvmsg` but if it's possible I would prefer to test the real code as much as I can.

Is there a way to induce `recvmsg` to return an error? For my current use case I don't care which error, as I handle all errors the same, but being able to induce particular errors would be a nice-to-have.

In case it matters, the socket I'm receiving from is a UDP socket.

Comment: How are you calling it in the test? Would simply `EBADF` from -1 as the socket work?

Comment: passing an invalid socket fd, like `-1`?

Comment: Ah that actually seems like it might work. I can friend the test to allow it to modify the `_fd` member variable of my objects, then when they later call `recvmsg` it will fail. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to make `recvmsg()` fail, without messing with the `_fd`, is to pass it a null `msghdr*`, or pass it invalid `flags`. That may be easier for your test to simulate than making the test be a `friend` of your library.